# Convert a List of Objects and convert into different format by comparing with same Id value

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

This is the list having data for different gender.

```
[
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "q": 358,
    "s": 158,
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "q": 328,
    "s": 258,
    "gender": "F"
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 3,
    "ageDesc": "15-59",
    "q": 525,
    "s": 125,
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "agCode": 4,
    "ageDesc": "60+",
    "q": 458,
    "s": 358,
    "gender": "F"
  }
]
```

The above list need to combine to the below list based on the ageCode is same. It need to merge the 2 objects where ageCode is same. The converted list look like below.

```
[
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "qM": 358,
    "sM": 158,
    "qF": 328,
    "sF": 258
  }
  {
    "ageCode": 3,
    "ageDesc": "15-59",
    "qM": 525,
    "sM": 125
  },
  {
    "agCode": 4,
    "ageDesc": "60+",
    "qF": 458,
    "sF": 358
  }
]
```

Solution tried:

```
  for(let item  of this.ageData) {
        if (this.ageData.find((i) => { i.agCode=== item.agCode})){

//}

    }
```

Here issues like duplicate and multiple for loop is required, Is there any efficient  way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try next.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "q": 358,
    "s": 158,
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "q": 328,
    "s": 258,
    "gender": "F"
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 3,
    "ageDesc": "15-59",
    "q": 525,
    "s": 125,
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 4,
    "ageDesc": "60+",
    "q": 458,
    "s": 358,
    "gender": "F"
  }
];

const combined = Object.values(data.reduce((result, item) => {
if (!result[item.ageCode]) {
  result[item.ageCode] = {ageCode: item.ageCode, ageDesc: item.ageDesc};
}
result[item.ageCode]['s' + item.gender] = item.s;
result[item.ageCode]['q' + item.gender] = item.q;
return result;
}, {}));

console.log(combined);
```

in case if you need sum up the numbers use the next thing:

```js
    result[item.ageCode]['s' + item.gender] = result[item.ageCode]['s' + item.gender] ? result[item.ageCode]['s' + item.gender] + item.s : item.s;
    result[item.ageCode]['q' + item.gender] = result[item.ageCode]['q' + item.gender] ? result[item.ageCode]['q' + item.gender] + item.q : item.q;
```

---

and the way back

```js
const combined = [
  {
    "ageCode": 1,
    "ageDesc": "0-4",
    "qM": 358,
    "sM": 158,
    "qF": 328,
    "sF": 258
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 3,
    "ageDesc": "15-59",
    "qM": 525,
    "sM": 125
  },
  {
    "ageCode": 4,
    "ageDesc": "60+",
    "qF": 458,
    "sF": 358
  }
];

const original = combined.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (item.qM !== undefined) {
    result.push({
      "ageCode": item.ageCode,
      "ageDesc": item.ageDesc,
      "q": item.qM,
      "s": item.sM,
      "gender": "M"
    });
  }
  if (item.qF !== undefined) {
    result.push({
      "ageCode": item.ageCode,
      "ageDesc": item.ageDesc,
      "q": item.qF,
      "s": item.sF,
      "gender": "F"
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(original);
```

Comment: Can you help me to convert back to same, while saving I need to convert back to the intial format ?

Comment: you mean to get the original array for the grouped one?

Comment: yes..  Do I need to add a separate question ?... I'm using multiple for loop its not working...

Comment: I've added the code, if it doesn't work - create a new question, ping me there with its link and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710616/split-a-combined-list-based-on-particular-gender-data-is-present-for-id

Comment: Done, please check the answer there

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
  listContact = [
    {
      "ageCode": 1,
      "ageDesc": "0-4",
      "q": 358,
      "s": 158,
      "gender": "M"
    },
    {
      "ageCode": 1,
      "ageDesc": "0-4",
      "q": 328,
      "s": 258,
      "gender": "F"
    },
    {
      "ageCode": 3,
      "ageDesc": "15-59",
      "q": 525,
      "s": 125,
      "gender": "M"
    },
    {
      "ageCode": 4,
      "ageDesc": "60+",
      "q": 458,
      "s": 358,
      "gender": "F"
    }
  ];
  listContact2 = [
    {
      "ageCode": 1,
      "ageDesc": "0-4",
      "qM": 358,
      "sM": 158,
      "qF": 328,
      "sF": 258
    },
    {
      "ageCode": 3,
      "ageDesc": "15-59",
      "qM": 525,
      "sM": 125
    },
    {
      "ageCode": 4,
      "ageDesc": "60+",
      "qF": 458,
      "sF": 358
    }
  ];
  uniqueListContact = [];
  flags = {};

...
this.uniqueListContact = [...this.listContact, ...this.listContact2];
this.uniqueListContact = this.uniqueListContact.filter((entry) => {
    if (this.flags[entry.ageCode]) {
        return false;
    }
    this.flags[entry.ageCode] = true;
    return true;
});
```

Here a complete working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-and-distinct-array-from-property?file=src/app/app.component.ts